# Has anyone used the AUTHORIZE.NET ECHECK.NET extension with Civi 4.4

Tags: payment-processor

We've tried installing it but the field snippet always displays the credit card field not the appropriate fields for an ACH transaction.

I've posted an issue on github but nothing positive yet.
https://github.com/donordepot/com.donordepot.authnetecheck/issues/11#issuecomment-168675840

Thanks

Comment: Did you get anywhere?  We need to implement on 4.7.  Maybe the iATS extension instead?

Comment: GH did you try this?